# Storing UnityManager in Session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unity-container

Please let me preface this by saying I am not very familiar with Unity.  I understand it is an dependency injection container and I understand to a limited degree what that means.  I inherited an application that uses Unity throughout although it does not seem to me to be implemented correctly.  In `session_start` of the `global.asa` the previous developer uses the following code to instantiate the unity object then persists it through the entire session:

```
var unity = new UnityManager(new UnityContainer());
Session["UnityManager"] = unity;
```

As I understand it wouldn't this inherently cause concurrency issues?  Can anyone provide an example of how to correctly implement unity or if this is correct explain to me why this is so?

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/shijuvarghese/archive/2011/01/21/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-mvc-3-using-dependencyresolver-and-controlleractivator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you're using mvc you could just remove the session and install unity.mvc3 from nuget package manager. It's compatible with mvc4 and sets it all up for you in a correct way. You can put the existing mappings in bootstrapper.cs (automatically installed)

Basically you want to have 1 static variable in the global.asax to access unity. So you can replace all those

```
var unitycontainer = Session["UnityManager"];
unitycontainer.resolve<>...
```

with

```
MVCApplication.Container.Resolve<> ..
```